# Get screen resolution php and ajax (for minimize sql query)

Tags: php

I wanted to get screen resolution with php so i used ajax but something went wrong...

İndex.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minimize sql please</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
        $width = $_POST["width"];
        echo $width;
?>
```

scripts.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://localhost/index.php',
        data:'width='+width,
        success:function(al){
            alert(al);
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: print your passed data in PHP file and check what data you are getting.

Comment: maybe `print json_encode($width);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Move your PHP code to a new file (let's say, ajax.php). Then change your script.js to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://localhost/ajax.php',
        data:'width='+width,
        success:function(al){
            alert(al);
        }
    });
});
```